# Galaxy S3 display issue

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen

I have a Galaxy S3 International Version, without any modification whatsoever.
However, of late, I have begun experiencing problems with my screen / display.

1. Graphics display issue
   The problem goes as follows: When I pull down the notification menu on the home screen slowly, I see that the the part of the screen that is visible is being displayed in poor quality. If i continue dragging, towards the last one third of the screen I begin to see banding similar to gradient banding.
2. Another issue, that goes in conjunction with the one above, is that the display seems to be grainy. Say, I press the apps button and see the icons of the apps I have installed. On top, where the option exists to see 'Widgets' or 'Apps' I see a grainy band run across those buttons. Grains can also be seen when browsing the internet or scrolling a list and so on.

I am unsure as to how to solve these problems. There are a few more 'problems' that I would like to discuss, probably on a different thread.
But for now, this is the one I have.

**Can someone please tell me how to solve this?**

Android Version: 4.1.2
Build Number: JZO54K.I9300XXEMF6

Comment: "without any modification" - does this include root?

Comment: It's still two questions you should have split into two posts (I'd suggest to ask a new question, moving one of the two over there). As for RAM: Please check the [ram tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ram/info); unused RAM is a wasted resource.

Comment: @Chahk Yes. I haven't rooted the phone at all. It is as good as stock with a few Play Store apps :)

Comment: @Izzy Ok done editing it into two parts. Here is the second one; http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54007/galaxy-s3-high-ram-consumption-even-on-idle

Comment: Just that I might add, grainy-ness also continues under brightness cranked up.

Comment: Thanks for splitting. That makes it much easier to answer. I've placed an answer to "the other part", hope it helps you sorting things out. No idea about this one here though, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy Went to a Samsung store pretending to be a customer interested in GS3. Saw the same issue in the stock phone. Haha !!

Comment: In that case it looks like a hardware issue, so we won't be able to help you with this here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Izzy Or maybe that it is OK as it is in all phones ?

Comment: I cannot tell, as I've not seen it first-hand. Up to you to decide then :)

Comment: @Izzy You can do me a favor by checking the GS3 at your nearest store :D

Comment: Is it a Kogan? Mine was like that until I cracked the screen, and the replacement was sharper and had no problems. Some International models are less than perfect.