# Is it possible to foce close all open apps with a single button

Tags: recents-screen

Is is possible to do a mass closure of all open apps. For example if i have 10 apps open is it possible for me to press a single button that says force close all open apps right now?

Comment: I cannot tell about force-close, but a simple "kill" would be possible using a task-killer. Still, that's not really recommended (see e.g. [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/54018/16575)). Is there a specific reason why you want to do this?

Comment: Are you just trying to hide apps from the recently-used list? Being in that list doesn't mean the app is running.